# App stalls on addPersistentStoreWithType with iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I have the following code in my persistentStoreCoordinator. Without the iCloud part, it works fine. With iCloud, it stops on the addPersistentStoreWithType method. No error, it just stops on it and doesn't continue.

Any thoughts?

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:STORE_PATH];

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];


        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
        NSLog(@"icloud: %@", iCloud);

        if (iCloud) {

            NSString *iCloudLogsDirectoryName = @"Logs";
            NSURL *iCloudLogsPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudLogsDirectoryName]];

            //Create logs directory, in case it doesn't exist
            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[iCloudLogsPath path]] == NO) {
                NSLog(@"logs directory doesn't exist");
                NSError *fileSystemError;
                [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudLogsDirectoryName]
                       withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                        attributes:nil
                                             error:&fileSystemError];
                if(fileSystemError != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Error creating logs directory %@", fileSystemError);
                }
            }

            NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"app id removed from stackoverflow";

            [options setObject:iCloudEnabledAppID            forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
            [options setObject:iCloudLogsPath                forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];
            NSLog(@"logs path: %@", iCloudLogsPath);
        }

    [_persistentStoreCoordinator lock];

    NSError *error;

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                   configuration:nil
                                                             URL:storeURL
                                                         options:options
                                                           error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"done adding persistent store");
    }

    [_persistentStoreCoordinator unlock];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomethingChanged" object:self userInfo:nil];
        [self.delegate contextWasSetupInManager:self];
    });

    });

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's common with iCloud. Apple advises you to put it on a background queue since that call may block. It blocks because that's where Core Data actually makes its connection to the iCloud server and starts downloading any new data that's available. The call doesn't continue until it's finished. If there's any significant amount of data to download, you may wait a while.

Sometimes it takes a while for no readily apparent reason. It's flaky like that.

Ultimately what you're seeing is pretty much the way things are with iCloud right now. File a bug or two and hope that things improve.

Comment: Would I be able to allow the user to continue using core data in my app, with this method running in the background?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can let this method run as long as it needs to run, but until it finishes you don't have a data store. That means you can't get anything into or out of Core Data. I've seen several ideas about how to deal with this but none that are really successful.

Comment: But doesn't that sort of.. destory my UX, that iCloud can just spend as long as it wants (minutes, hours) holding the user at the same point and not let them use the app otherwise? Surely there's a way around this, an alternative?

Comment: Yes, it's a problem for your UX. As for alternatives, I've been working on alternative approaches for a while but still haven't reached the point where I would ship an app with Core Data + iCloud. You might want to consider alternative approaches-- or be prepared to come up with your own creative approach to getting Core Data + iCloud to not suck.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this on one of my test devices (iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1). Doing a factory reset and then restoring from a current backup of the phone fixed it.

I'm not sure that this is the explanation, but there seems to be an issue with deleting an app's iCloud ubiquity container data through device Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup. This might put the device into a state where some remnants of the ubiquity container remain and cannot be removed. Doing a full wipe and restore on the device seems to fix it.

I found an old post that looked like it was related this issue (http://stackmonthly.com/2011/11/core-data), and this entry on OpenRadar (http://openradar.appspot.com/10440734). I messed around with it for several hours until I wiped and restored the device, which worked perfectly: the addPersistentStoreWithType completed almost instantly.

Moving forward I'm going to try to clear the store using the nukeAndPave method in the WWDC 2012 sample application SharedCoreData (session 227) rather than manually deleting the store from Settings. Hopefully that will prevent this situation from recurring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure why these issues come up but I have had a lot of success in getting around problems of this nature by doing a reset of the phone's settings:

Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings